Pacstrap can't install iptables, even thougn it's already installed
I am trying to install Arch Linux ARM on my Nintendo 3DS and I have a pacman.conf file that looks like this:

HoldPkg     = pacman glibc
Architecture = armv6h
#SigLevel    = Required DatabaseOptional
SigLevel    = Never
LocalFileSigLevel = Optional

[core]
Server = http://mirror.archlinuxarm.org/armv7h/core

[extra]
Server = http://mirror.archlinuxarm.org/armv7h/extra

[community]
Server = http://mirror.archlinuxarm.org/armv7h/community

[alarm]
Server = http://mirror.archlinuxarm.org/armv7h/alarm

[aur]
Server = http://mirror.archlinuxarm.org/armv7h/aur

ignore the different architectures
And it gives me this error:
error: could not open file /mnt/root/var/cache/pacman/pkg/iptables-1:1.8.10-2-armv7h.pkg.tar.xz.part: Invalid argument
error: failed to setup a download payload for iptables-1:1.8.10-2-armv7h.pkg.tar.xz
warning: failed to retrieve some files
error: failed to commit transaction (failed to retrieve some files)
Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded.
==> ERROR: Failed to install packages to new root

I have tried wget directly into the mirror for that specific file, and got a file named iptables-1_1.8.10-2-armv7h.pkg.tar.xz, which can't be renamed to iptables-1:1.8.10-2-armv7h.pkg.tar.xz, as that is an invalid filename. What should I do?

What filesystem do you have mounted on /mnt/root? That absolutely is a valid file name on every filesystem that would be suitable for use as a rootfs filesystem.

It's an exfat filesystem

Why are you installing Linux on an exfat filesystem?
